# Что делать, если чувствую что видеокарта сдыхает?

Tags: windows, железо, nvidia

Время от времени на экране высыпаются артефакты, пау раз просто пропадала картинка, а звук шел. Видуху брал Б/Ушную ASUS GeForce GTX 760 2Гб в поставщика железа с Европы, 2 года отпахала, ничего серьезней доты там не запускал.
Как протестовать, ли видео это?

Comment: Как протестировать - очень просто. Надо временно поставить другую видюху. Если сбои прекратятся, то значит дело было в видеоплате. Если не прекратятся - значит дело в чем-то другом.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по описанию - перегрев видео-карты. У меня было с теми же симптомами. Купил GeForce 1050 GTX за 120 или 150 евро - все прошло.

Comment: Как самому убедиться в этой неисправности? Прогнать через какой-то тестер типа Ади64? Но если там действительно беда с охлаждением, не сгорит ли карточка?

Comment: Насчет тестов - трудно. Померить температуру видюхи как-то. При перегреве она будет каждый раз случайные ошибки делать (показывать не то, зависать и т.п.), поэтому таких тестов нет, вроде. И сгорит она в любом случае. В моем случае она еще монитор испортила напоследок. У меня была GeForce 740 GTX.

Comment: Вы умеете подбодрить! Спасибо!

Comment: А делать что что? Мне монитор жалко (хоть он и старый)

Comment: Я новую видюху купил geforce 1050 gtx

Comment: Эту можно уже сегодня скручивать и выносить в железный контейнер возле дома?

Comment: Типа того. С такими симптомами моя карта жила до лета. И потом сожгла монитор и себя.